# Dimension of the constant in Born-Infeld nonlinear electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, dimensional-analysis, non-linear-systems

As I know, based on the Lagrangian of Born-Infeld electrodynamics, its constant which shows the strength of electromagnetic field should have the dimension of inverse of length, but in some papers I saw it should be mass or the inverse square of length! Can anybody say the correct dimension of it? and prove it?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born–Infeld_model) article for the relevant equation.

Comment: $b$ has the units of field strength (in, say, Gaussian units where electric and magnetic field strengths have the same units).

Comment: You need to show the equations that are confusing you.

Comment: In natural units where $\hbar$ and $c$ are 1, the dimensions of field strength (and thus $b$) are mass-squared or inverse-length-squared.